# How to configure User access while printing from an workstation to an MFD

Tags: printer, network-printer

I have a Ricoh Multifunction Device.

I have profiled some Users on the device's Address book with user codes.
I also set up permitted features for copying, printing and scanning.

Whenever I try to copy, an authentication screen prompts up (AS EXPECTED).

But when I try to print from a workstation, the job log says "This user does not have the privileges to perform this function. This job has been cancelled".

I have tried adding the username and password (created from the printer's address book) on the Computer's Print driver preferences page; yet it keeps giving same error.

Please who has had to deal with this kind of error in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Just incase someone comes across this.

The simple fix is to install the PCL 5c driver for the MFD. It has the "valid access" tab, where you get to input the user code to be authenticated.

The PCL 6 lacks that tab thus making it impossible to verify who prints.

Comment: It is still in the PCL6 driver; go to Detail Settings, and then Job Setup - you'll see both the User Code and Authentication options there.

Comment: They don't work. At least for me. I tried everything with the pcl6 driver to no avail.